# How to add reset button in Dialog box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to add a RESET button in dialog box whose work is to delete the Hidden field value from database and close the dialog box:

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenPopup() {

    var data = document.getElementById('<%=hflinkData.ClientID %>').value;

    var keyval = data.split(';');

    var table = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < keyval.length; i++) {
        var arr = keyval[i].split('=');
        table += "<tr><td>" + arr[0] + "</td><td>" + arr[1] + "</td></tr>";


    }
    table += '</table>';

    $('#WindowBody').html(table);

    $('#dialogWindow').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true,
              height: 200,
              width: 500,
              title: "Device Info",
              resizable: false,
              draggable: false,
              position: ['center', 'center'],
              closeOnEscape: true,
              open: function (event, ui)
              {
                  $('.ui-dialog').css('top', 100);
              },
              create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed'); }

    });

    $('#dialogWindow').dialog('open');
    return false;
}
```

`

and this my HTML code

```
<div id="dialogWindow" >
        <label></label>
        <div id="WindowBody">
        </div>                      
    </div>`
```

Where "hflinkData" is the name of hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use ajax post to achieve your requirement. Use normal html input button inside dialog. Kindly see the below code snippet.

```
<div id="dialogWindow" >
    <label></label>
    <div id="WindowBody">
    </div>   
 <input type="button" onclick="deleteValue();" value="RESET" />                   
</div>
```

And send the AJAX post to code behind in 'deleteValue' method. Please see the below javascript code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteValue() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/DeleteData",
            type: "POST",
            data: {value:$("#hflinkData").val()},
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

And write the required code for delete operation in code behind.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void DeleteData(string value)
    {
        //get the hidden value from parameter
        //code for delete corresponding value from data base
    }
```

Regards,
Sunil Prabakar C

Comment: Sir button is working but my value is show like DataValue Undefined,DataCoontext Undefined,,DataTaxt xyz .i dont want to display the undefined value row.how is this posible plz help

Comment: Data text XYZ and i want that the undefined value row will not diaplay in dialog box .plz help

Comment: aparana, i din't get you. where do u got undefined value. in WebMethod DeleteData()?. Pls clearly explain with some more details